# Check for array and print values in Zend Framework

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework, database

I am adding a number of thumbnail images to an article, new to Zend Framework so i'm not sure about the coding style for printing this array.

My array in MongoDB looks like this:

```
"thmbs": [
    {
        "src": "examp.com/img/product1.jpg",
        "caption": "Top View"
    },
    {
        "src": "examp.com/img/product2.jpg",
        "caption": "Side View"
    },
]
```

First i want to check the array to see if it contains anything, then print the images & captions for the alt text. Is this the right direction do go??

```
       <?php if ($this->thmbs) {
          foreach($this->thmbs->src as $val){?>
              <img id="lead-image" src="<?= $this->thmbs->src ?>"  alt="<?= $this->thmbs->caption?>"/>
       <?php }} ?>
```

Comment: It's a perfectly good way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with MongoDB but if it gives you the output in what looks to be JSON format, simply convert it to a php array using `json_decode()`. For example:

```
<?php

   $this->thmbs = json_decode($db_output, true);
   if($this->thmbs){
      foreach( $this->thmbs as $thmb ){
         echo "<img id='lead-image' src='". $thmb->src ."' alt='". $thmb->caption ."' />";
      }
   }

?>
```